# Finding probability from a markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

If I have a markov chain transition matrix for 2 states.
Specifically in my case, it is a transition matrix for a bacterial genome with 4 random variables being A,C,G and T. (The bases)
If I want to calculate the probability of a random sequence like GATTACA occurring from the markov chain, how would I go about it?

I was thinking that I would have to do it by :

P(A|G) * P(T|A) * P(T|T) * P(A|T) * P(C|A) * P(A|C)

But I am not sure what to do with the first G. Do I take its probability as 1 or do I use the stationary distribution of transition matrix value for G?

Comment: Do you mean 4 states ACGT, not 4 random variables?

Comment: You would need either the initial distribution or the initial starting state.

Comment: @gt6989b I actually used the word states for them first, but I thought it might be confusing since I already said that markov chain was for 2 states. (Ti and Ti-1).

Comment: @gt6989b, can I use the stationary distribution matrix for P as the initial starting state?

Comment: @gaddaga The Markov chain has 4 states, not 2. Your 2 does not enumerate the states, in fact it is 1 + the length of the memory of the Markov process.

Comment: @gaddaga what do you mean by the stationary distribution matrix? from my point of view, you cannot take the probability of G as one - what you would need to look at is the percentage of G in the entire bacterial genome. For example, if P(G|A), P(G|T), P(G|C) were all very small, then the percentage of G in the population would be very small too.

Comment: @Did, Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @VincentTjeng By Stationary Distrubition matrix I mean a matrix pi such that pi = pi*P where P is the transition matrix.

Comment: @VincentTjeng If I were given only the transition matrix, how would I get the probability of G then?

Comment: @VincentTjeng *For example, if P(G|A), P(G|T), P(G|C) were all very small, then the percentage of G in the population would be very small too*... Not necessarily.

Comment: @Did would it be more correct to say that if P(G|A),P(G|T),P(G|C) and P(G|G) were all less than k, then P(G)<k too?

Comment: @gaddaga So your question is not really a mathematical one. You should me more precise about the experiment in which you are interested; how do you sample the finite sequence in the genome ?

Comment: @VincentTjeng Definitely.

Comment: @gadagga I would take the stationary distribution matrix only if your bacterial genome were long enough and the Markov Chain is aperiodic, at least. not sure what additional conditions we should add.